# htaccess: How to redirect a file: disclaimer_en.html/disclaimer_fr.html detecting the browser language

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, multilingual

I'm totally new to htaccess files and I'm trying to redirect every URL comming to /disclaimer folder to a different folder where you can find files of the type:

```
 disclaimer_en.html
 disclaimer_es.html
 disclaimer_fr.html
```

I need the _language to be a variable, is this possible? I'm trying with something like this:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (ar|en|es|fr|zh) [NC]
 RewriteRule /disclaimer /pages/disclaimer/disclaimer_$1.html [L]
```

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(ar|en|es|fr|zh) [NC]
RewriteRule ^disclaimer /pages/disclaimer/disclaimer_%1.html [L,NC]
```